# Placing Values from Anchor to Modal Bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

i have a problem. I have some php script that create list of post in my database.

this is the code

```
<td><?php echo "$r[date_create]"; ?></td>
<td><?php echo "$r[date_update]"; ?></td>
<td><?php echo "$r[hitcount]"; ?></td>
<td>
 <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo "$r[id]"; ?>"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
 <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" id="<?php $r[id]; ?>">
 <i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
</td>
```

This syntax is calling a modal called MyModal

as you can see, the anchor (

```
<a href="#myModal"
```

) getting some id based on database

But i can't by pass the value generated from the php script to my modal window

here's the modal window syntax

```
<div class="modal small hide fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p class="error-text">Are you sure you want to delete the post?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" href="delete.php?id=THE ID SHOULD BE HERE  ">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to the ID from anchor above is place on the delete.php?id=THE ID SHOULD BE HERE

how to do that?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You will have to manually open the modal box, instead of relying on the data attributes to do the job. A pseudo-code could be like this:

```
$(function() {
  // Attach a click handler to your link
  $('#modal_opener').click(function() {
    // Open the modal box
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    // Set the id to the hidden field
    $('#id_on_your_modal').val("<?php print $r[id] ?>");
  });
});
```

Remember that the javascript code must be in the same page of your html code, so you can have access to your php variables.